# How to Render Cross Section without Slicing the Mesh Geometry?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, rendering, modeling

Given a slice plane in the world, I want triangles to be seen if they were on the positive side of the plane, and those who
intersect with the plane are split and the part on positive plane can be seen too.

If I slice the triangles meshes every time when plane is changed, it may be very slow when there are tons of triangles, and texture coordinate will be re-generated too.

If I set the camera(view) and projection carefully, it may generate similar result, but this result is view dependent.

So, is there render techniques which can utilize clipping result from GPU to render the view independent cross section?

cross section like this: [image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using shaders is this really easy. In **Opengl/GLSL** you just add an `if` statement to fragment shader determining if your fragment is on the correct side of your plane and if not `discard` it.

That will cut your object by your condition so you will get the contours. However you still have to handle the filling somehow possibly from depth buffer in second pass or by using stencil buffer but both are just single `GL_QUAD` covering whole screen.

The math to do this is simple you need to define your half space. The simplest thing I can think of is:

`p0=(x0,y0,z0)` - 3D point belonging to cutting plane

 `n0=(nx,ny,nz)` - normal to cutting plane pointing to wards viewed side

so any fragment `p=(x,y,z)` is visible if

```
dot_product(p-p0,n0) >= 0.0
```

so

```
if (nx*(x-x0)+ny*(y-y0)+nz*(z-z0)<0.0f) discard;
```

Do not forget to disable `GL_CULL_FACE` and using double sided matherials/lighting. Also all the coordinates must be in the same coordinate system !!!

Comment: That's very simple and elegant idea, i'm going to test it, thanks. I think i should develop some skills on GPU shaders.